# I create intent to link to other interface but end up force close

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my Login.java code

```
package com.pmss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Login extends Activity {

Button login, register;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //startActivity(new Intent());
        }
    });
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(new Intent(intent));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This is my Register.java
    package com.pmss;

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class Register extends ActionBarActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.pmss.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    /*MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.register, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);*/
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.register, menu);
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    // searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterNextPart.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void openSearch(){

}

public void openSettings(){

}



}
```

I wonder is it anything to do with this coding:

```
register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(new Intent(intent));
        }
    });
```

When run on my mobile phone and I tap register button which end up force close the application. Anybody help me? really new to ADT

And This is my logcat

```
11-23 22:09:32.029: W/dalvikvm(15739): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 7433: Landroid/view/MenuItem;.getActionView ()Landroid/view/View;
11-23 22:09:32.169: D/AndroidRuntime(15739): Shutting down VM
11-23 22:09:32.169: W/dalvikvm(15739): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MenuItem.getActionView
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at com.pmss.Register.onCreateOptionsMenu(Register.java:36)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2158)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:70)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-23 22:09:32.169: E/AndroidRuntime(15739):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add the logcat to your question please. Did you declare all your activities in your manifest ?

Comment: Please add your logcat output

Comment: I declared all activities in my manifest

Comment: I have posted my logcat on the questions~

Comment: Anyway, I did something about my actionbar, and the errors for force close eventually gone off. Thanks you all the helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `register` button `setOnClickListener` code to

```
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And Don't Forget to add Activity in your Manifest File

```
<activity
    android:name=".Register"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: I dont get it for the register button setOnCLickListener code.... which one to change?

Comment: In your `Login.java` file, you have written line `startActivity(new Intent(intent));` in `setOnClickListener` of `register` button... Change this line to `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: If the problem still exists, post your logcat

Comment: The problem still exist, I have already posted the logcat on the bottom part of the question
@Rehan

Comment: Anyway, I did something about my actionbar, and the errors for force close eventually gone off. Thanks you all the helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ther are so many cases why this error is occured.

1) May be you have forgot to add Register activity to your Menifest File.
2) The ID which you are providing for registed is wrong

and so other also, It's very hard to tell without logcat. But this are cases which might occur.